# Could you check my GAS please? / Auto posting files from Google Drive to Google Chat

Tags: google-apps-script

Cloud you review my code and give me advice?

1. Aim of this code
   Send a PDF, which is located in Google Shared Drive, to a Chat Room by a GAS trigger.
   With this trigger, send message which is put in the spreadsheet.
2. My Code

```
function test() {

  //var report = DriveApp.getFilesByName('sales.pdf').next(); //PDF NAME
  var report = '1PHxovEmLipUTSm73C6JzWBeyn4p3KZYdc2JEIsbOIyI';　//PDF FILE-ID

/* Spreadsheet */
  let sheetName = 'sheet1';
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // Message
  let TEXT = sheet.getRange(2 , 1).getValues();


/* Hangout Chat */  
  // Direction
  const url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAgnKGQ60/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=W9JssgpcVLtibnP6zZYIii9pfodXBWWlpheaSFeXjEs%3D'; // ChatRoom Webhook

    // Create the post
    let message = {'text' : text,attachments: report} //Attach File？
    let params = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'headers' : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      },
      'payload':JSON.stringify(message)
    };

    // Sender
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

3. Error of this code

```
Exception: Request failed for https://chat.googleapis.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"attachments\" at 'message': Cannot find field.",
    ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

4. Ask

Could you please point out the mistakes in my code and please tell me the correct one.

Regards,
Mariko

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- `TEXT` of `let TEXT = sheet.getRange(2 , 1).getValues();` is not used. The variable name of `TEXT` is not the same with `text`. Please be careful this.
- From the error message of `Unknown name \"attachments\" at 'message': Cannot find field."`, in the current stage, it seems that `attachments` is not existing in the properties of `message`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#Message) In this case, please use `attachment`. And the value of this property is an array. The object of `attachment` can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages.attachments#resource:-attachment).

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). Because this modified script retrieves the values for `attachment` with the files.get method of Drive API v2.

```
function test() {
  var fileId = '1PHxovEmLipUTSm73C6JzWBeyn4p3KZYdc2JEIsbOIyI'; //PDF FILE-ID
  var report = Drive.Files.get(fileId);

  /* Spreadsheet */
  let sheetName = 'sheet1';
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // Message
  let text = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getValues();

  /* Hangout Chat */
  // Direction
  const url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAgnKGQ60/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=W9JssgpcVLtibnP6zZYIii9pfodXBWWlpheaSFeXjEs%3D'; // ChatRoom Webhook

  // Create the post
  let message = {
    text: text,
    attachment: [{
      contentName: report.title,
      contentType: report.mimeType,
      thumbnailUri: report.thumbnailLink,
      downloadUri: report.webContentLink,
      source: "DRIVE_FILE"
    }]
  };
  let params = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(message)
  };

  // Sender
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your endpoint of `url` is the valid value. Please be careful this.
- **When I saw your file ID of `PDF FILE-ID`, the length of your file ID is 44. In this case, I'm worry that your file ID might be Google Docs file which is not the PDF file. So please be careful this. Please confirm whether your file ID is the file ID of the PDF file again.**
- If an error occurs for `attachment`, at first, please test your script without `attachment` using the following script.

  ```
    function test2() {
      const url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAgnKGQ60/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=W9JssgpcVLtibnP6zZYIii9pfodXBWWlpheaSFeXjEs%3D';
      let params = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify({text: "sample text"})
      };
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      console.log(res.getContentText())
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [spaces.messages.create](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create)
- [spaces.messages.attachments](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages.attachments#Attachment)

Comment: Hi Tahaike-san,

Thank you for your huge support! 

I all cleared what I need to fix in my code.

Additionally, you gave me some references and sources to learn more about this topics. 

Thank you again. I'll try by following your guide.

Regards,
Mariko

Comment: @Mariko Chida Thank you for replying. When my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.